# sqlite datetime unixepoch and ms

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a datetime value in unixepoch but also in ms. Anyone know how I can print the string version of the time WITH milliseconds?
i.e.

```
Field value is 1401795533345
```

So to get string I use,

```
select datetime(MeasureTime/1000,  'unixepoch') from Stats
I get 2014-06-03 11:38:53
but Im not able to get the 345ms printed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) instead:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', MeasureTime/1000, 'unixepoch') FROM Stats
```

Comment: Thank you. I just found that too. Actually SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', MeasureTime*1.0/1000, 'unixepoch') FROM Stats